# Android virtual device

Tags: android

When i am running my application as shown below error shows can you tell me what is the problem.

```
[2012-03-28 23:32:53 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-03-28 23:32:53 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Documents and Settings\atar singh\.android\avd\Android_4.0.3.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-03-28 23:32:53 - Emulator] ko:Snapshot storage already in use: C:\Documents and Settings\atar singh\.android\avd\Android_4.0.3.avd/snapshots.img
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problem **the GUI way**:

Go to DDMS perspective, click on the down arrow next to the screen capture camera icon and select reset adb from the dropdown menu.

From the **command line**:

Open the cmd.exe command prompt. Locate ABD.exe in SDK folder "..\android-sdk\platform-tools\abd.exe"

`cd <sdk directory>` (move to the folder listed above)

`dir` (to make sure abd.exe is in that directory)

`adb kill-server` (stop the abd service, won't return anything)

`adb start-server` (start the abd service back up)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have running a process from avd (could be previous one which was not closed properly). Try looking for avd process and kill it.

Comment: how to do this can u tell me becoze we many time exit the process and restart it but it show same error again and again

Comment: If you're using windows look with the task manager (CTRL+ALT+delete) in tab processes for process with name avd or similar and then click "end process"

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above solutions without success. They may help in some cases, but not all.

To clear the "already in use" problem without losing the state of your AVD, the specific files you need to delete are the "pid" files in the .lock directories under YourAVDName.avd. I did this while the AVD was not running, but I didn't test it without closing the AVD, so I don't know for certain if that is necessary (though it seems logical.)