# Android reuse sd card for multiple emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

How to reuse a sd card for multiple android emulators so there is no need keep the files in sd card multiple times while testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Read up on how to create an img sdcard file

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html

2) Use the sdcard file here where it says file while creating a new emulator device
[image]

And in case you see locking errors - follow instructions here: [Android emulator sd card image already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021471/android-emulator-sd-card-image-already-in-use)

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, ipreviously didnt worked with command prompt while working as in link i am getting "'mksdcard' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Thats because its not in your windows path environment - give the full path and try - it should be present in the android sdk folder -  `...\sdk\tools\mksdcard.exe`

Comment: Or you could just create a new card with the avd, it will create a card in the `\users\username\.android` folder in windows, and then you can reuse that.